# Using python multiprocessing to log into routers

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cisco

I'm a bit new to coding/scripting in general and need some help implementing multiprocessing.

I currently have two functions that I'll concentrate on here. The first, `def getting_routes(router):`logs into all my routers (the list of routers comes from a previous function) and runs a command. The second function `def parse_paths(routes): parses the results of this command.

```
def get_list_of_routers 
<some code> 
    return routers

def getting_routes(router):
    routes = sh.ssh(router, "show ip route")
    return routes

def parse_paths(routes):
    l = routes.split("\n")
...... <more code>.....
return parsed_list
```

My list is roughly 50 routers long and along with subsequent parsing, takes quite a bit of time so I'd like to use the multiprocessing module to run the sshing into routers, command execution, and subsequent parsing in parallel across all routers. 
I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
def get_list_of_routers  (***this part does not need to be threaded)
<some code> 
    return routers

def getting_routes(router):
    routes = sh.ssh(router, "show ip route")
    return routes

def parse_paths(routes):
    l = routes.split("\n")
...... <more code>.....
    return parsed_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=getting_routes)
    worker_2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=parse_paths)


   worker_1.start()
   worker_2.start()
```

What I'd like is for parallel sshing into a router, running the command, and returning the parsed output. I've been reading http://kmdouglass.github.io/posts/learning-pythons-multiprocessing-module.html and the multiprocessing module but am still not getting the results I need and keep getting undefined errors. Any help with what I might be missing in the multiprocessing module? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not sending the *router* parameter to the *getting_routes* function.

Also, I think using threads will be sufficient, you don't need to create new processes.

What you need to do is create a loop in you main block that will start a new thread for each router that is returned from the *get_list_of_routers* function. Then you have two options - either call the *parse_paths* function from within the thread, or get the return results from the threads and then call the parse_paths.

For example:
    import Queue
    from threading import Thread

```
que = Queue.Queue()
threads = []


for router in get_list_of_routers():
    t = Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(getting_routers(arg1)), args=(que, router))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)


for t in threads:
    t.join()


results = []
while not que.empty():
    results.append(que.get())


parse_paths(results)
```